micropython stm32F722ze, ValueError: Pin(PC13) doesn't exist
I am using stm32f722ze and trying to write a program to control led using push button but it always says value error. With the help of user manual figure out the Arduino mapping for PC0 but cannot find for PC13. Is there any way I will be able to execute this program. I am using Thonny IDE. I tried to look user manual and reference manual for pin mapping. Tried ChatGPT as well as browsing the web. I need help to either find the alternate name for pc13 that is accessible to MicroPython command pyb.Pin or any other way to execute the code.
import pyb

def main():

    green_led = pyb.Pin('D33', mode =pyb.Pin.OUT_PP)

    button = pyb.Pin('PC13', mode = pyb.Pin.IN, pull = pyb.Pin.PULL_DOWN)

    while True:

        if button.value() == 0:
            green_led.value(1)
        else:
            green_led.value(0)

main()


stm32f722ze refers to the MCU not the board.  Presumably you are referring to  STMicroelectronics NUCLEO-F722ZE?

It is not clear why you mention PC0 - that maps to A1. D33 in your code refers to PB0.

Your failed attempts and method used are largely irrelevant, as is the IDE you are using.  With respect to "browsing the web", "browsing" is not the same as "searching" (effectively).  I searched on "NUCLEO-F722ZE accessing button in micropython", The first link led me to the Github repo where the mapping is documented. You perhaps need to hone your search skills rather than programming skills or relying AI to give you answers.

... interesting experiment.  I asked Gemini "What is the micropython pin mapping for NUCLEO-F722ZE?", it gave a vague recommendation to read the documentation or access community support.  I then told it how I found the answer using real intelligence.  Now when I ask it the same question, it directs me to the resource I informed it of.  So I made it "smarter"! ;-)

Noting that the "intelligence" of generative AI in this case is in producing results in "natural language" not in "knowing" actual facts for which it is relying on the same body of knowledge you can find yourself by a web-search.  AI appears "smart" only when its search-foo is better than yours, and you are not going to get better at it relying on AI.  This is why it is better not to mention your use of AI to find an answer.  It is irrelevant and just triggers this kind of strident opinion on the benefits of AI, and the wisdom of relying on it.

According to https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/ports/stm32/boards/NUCLEO_F722ZE/pins.csv  PC13 is mapped to the I/O names 'SW' and 'SW_SD'.  So:
button = pyb.Pin('SW', mode = pyb.Pin.IN, pull = pyb.Pin.PULL_DOWN)

Note however that the NUCLEO-F722ZE switch already has a pull-down:

(https://www.st.com/resource/en/schematic_pack/nucleo_144pins_sch.zip).
So, I would suggest:
button = pyb.Pin('SW', mode = pyb.Pin.IN, pull = pyb.Pin.None)

